# Did I just break an SD card Size Adapter with software?

Tags: linux

I am wondering whether what apparently just happened here is possible.

I used `dd` to erase the MBR of a microSD Card in my built-in Card Reader, which only accepts the large SD Cards - so I was using one of those microSD Size Adapters (by Kingston.)

I had been using the Adapter all evening, and for a few weeks before that, and it had always worked.

Now, right after the MBR deletion, I could not read the SD Card anymore - of course I thought it was the missing MBR, but it turned out I could read it with a different *Size Adapter* (a Verbatim one.)

The Kingston Adapter stopped working right after the MBR deletion. It's not working with other microSD Cards anymore, neither. It's just metal and plastic. Did I really break metal and plastic, no active components, using a `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1`?

Comment: This belongs back on EESE where it was originally and correctly asked, as evidenced by the fact that the issue is with the sd *adapter*, not any *card*, it has to be a problem with the *passive circuitry* in the adapter, not a software configuration one at all.

Comment: Is your card reader properly grounded? Could've had a short which messed up the card in the first place.

Comment: It is built-in to my laptop, but if I get around to it today I think I'll open it up and have a look at it with the multimeter. Come to think of it, maybe I can see something on the oscilloscope, like unwanted capacities lurking around, or something, I don't know. I'm a bit unwilling to repeat the experiment, as I need to do some work with an adapter, and I only have the one more lying around. But I will try to repeat this.

Answer (score 8):

Every adapter I have seen has been a simple assembly of physical contacts with no other circuit elements.

However, I have seen a lot of them (including name brand ones) arrive or subsequently go bad, which is presumably a failure of the contacts to contact.

stefandz makes an interesting point about the write protect switch, but the failures I have seen were ones where the host system could not detect the presence of a card at all.  The same card would then work in another adapter.

Comment: Good point about contact corrosion - I have only ever seen this once, and it was visible. Think it may have been tea related in my case... But more consistent with the OP's symptoms than my answer, which should only stop modification of data.

Comment: Although it is certainly possible, I don't think the cases I saw were corrosion, more failure to achieve physical contact based on poor design of the spring leaves and/or housing.  I've also seen the housings split, which is what lead to knowledge of the internals.

Comment: It is as you describe, the cards in this adapter are not visible to the host system any more.

Answer (score 4):

There is absolutely no way that you damaged a microSD to SD card adapter using a software command. They are simple interconnect devices.

However, stupidly (IMHO) they often keep the slide switch that enables card lock on a full size SD card (this switch does not exist for microSD). If this switch is in the down position (switch towards the middle of the card) you will not be able to modify the card contents (although you **should** still be able to view the contents of the card).

Try sliding this switch to the up position (towards the end of the card) and see if that helps.

Comment: I cannot see the micro SD card (or another) on my system with this adapter any more at all. They don't show up in `dmesg` output, `fdisk -l`, or anywhere. The lockswitch is still in the (unlocked) Up Position, as it was. I did not touch the adapter after the MBR erase, the card remained in it, it just became invisible to the system, which is why I am wondering about all this.